# Duplicate Interface Definition in iPhone Project when Archiving

Tags: xcode4.2, ios5

I am having an intermittent issue with Xcode trying to archive my project. The project builds to the phone and simulator with no issues but when I go to archive it I get duplicate interface definition. This strange problem with this is that where it is telling me the issue is it is also telling me that this is the location of the previous definition too. So I'm thinking there isn't an issue at all. I have had this problem before and it went away without me doing anything. I can use the build for archiving option in the product menu but when I select archive from that menu the problem occurs. Very strange, any help would be great, thanks. iOS 5 Xcode 4.2.

Comment: When you improve your accept ratio, people will be willing to help you.